# How to use a html dropdown to fill in a Symfony2 form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony

I’m attempting to use a dropdown that has values from an array and when a user clicks on one of those values, that value gets put into a textfield.

The problem I’m having is that the textfield is built in a Symfony2 form. How can I put the selected dropdown value in that textfield?

example…I can’t create a fiddle because it wouldn’t illustrate my issue…

```
<div id=“myText”> {{ form_row(form.informationKey) }} </div>   //this is a textfield

 <div class = "dropdowns">
      <select id = "dropdown">
                <option value="default"> default </option>
                      {% for key, value in mation %}
                          <option value="{{ key }} | {{ val }}"> {{ key }} | {{ value }} </option>
                      {% endfor %}        
       </select>
  </div>
```

JavaScript...

```
// Set textfield input to selected dropdown option
    var myTextBox = document.getElementById('myText');
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

     myDropdown.onchange = function () {
           myTextBox.value = this.value;
      }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? it should work like you describe... if you know the textbox #id, then you can assign value to it with javascript anytime

Comment: sorry, the problem is that is doesn't populate the textfield. I see in console the dropdown is working but I think my issue is that I'm not accessing the correct value input of the textfield. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hey @Miro... me typing out my actual problem help me solve it. so thanks!